# Display an image from an fetch API response, but it won't display. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

```js
const url = "https://api.rawg.io/api/games/4200";

async function createGameDetails() {
  const heading = document.querySelector("h1");

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const info = await response.json();

    

    heading.innerHTML = info.name;

    const image = document.querySelector(".image");
    image.innerHTML = info.background_image;

    const description = document.querySelector(".description");
    description.innerHTML = info.description;
  } catch (error) {
    heading.innerHTML = "error.";
    console.log(error);
  }
}

createGameDetails();
```

```css
.image {
  height: 200px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/question3.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Name of game</h1>
      <div
        class="image"
        style="background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/1000');"
      ></div>
      <div class="description">Description goes here</div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/question3.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to fetch an API response and it to display a `background_image` in my image div with an image class, but it won't show. What am I doing wrong? I am posting the JavaScript, CSS and the HTML under here in case someone can have a look. I will be so very thankful for any answer that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the background image style of the element instead of `innerHtml`.

```js
const url = "https://api.rawg.io/api/games/4200";

async function createGameDetails() {
  const heading = document.querySelector("h1");

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const info = await response.json();



    heading.innerHTML = info.name;

    const image = document.querySelector(".image");
    
    //changed this line
    image.style.backgroundImage = `url(${info.background_image})`;
    const description = document.querySelector(".description");
    description.innerHTML = info.description;
  } catch (error) {
    heading.innerHTML = "error.";
    console.log(error);
  }
}

createGameDetails();
```

```css
.image {
  height: 200px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/question3.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Name of game</h1>
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/1000');"></div>
    <div class="description">Description goes here</div>
  </div>

  <script src="js/question3.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```